# export TGFF output to a C/C++ structure

Tags: c++, c

I want to let TGFF export its output as a graph data structure in C or C++. Is it possible to do so?
As far as I know, TGFF can output EPS and VCG format. Can we import them to C/C++ so that the graph can be processed?

Answer (score 0):

The TGFF output format is simple and textual, easy to parse by reading from the stream. Take a look at one of the output files; it should be self-explanatory.